# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .NET Core WebAPI being hosted on IIS that I have enabled CORS in the startup.cs.

When making a request to the API from my Angular app, the request fails and i get this error

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test-api.contractorconnection.com/ERCore_Service/api/LandingPage/Authenticate/Austin.Born/ERCore' from origin 'https://test-apps2.contractorconnection.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

When making the request directly from the browser or postman, the request completes and I get my data.

I have tried many answers, modifying the *web.config*, and specifying the allowed origins in the *Startup.cs*

What am I missing here or doing incorrectly?

Startup.cs below

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //  //For JWT Auth
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
    services.AddScoped<ILandingPage, DAL_LandingPage>();
    services.AddScoped<IDetails, DAL_EstimateDetailPage>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueueDetailsPage, DAL_QueueDetails>();
    services.AddScoped<IAdminDetailPage, DAL_AdminDetailPage>();
    services.AddScoped<IAdminCatSelTab, DAL_AdminCatSel>();
    services.AddScoped<IApplicationSecurityTab, DAL_ApplicationSecurityTab>();

    //services.AddCors();
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder => {
        builder.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("https://test-apps2.contractorconnection.com", "https://test-apps2.contractorconnection.com/ERCore", "http://localhost:54807/")
            .AllowCredentials();
    }));

    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
            = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    });
    services.AddDbContext<PrismDataContext1>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));



}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    //app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://cc-er-dev-api.primussoft.com", "https://test-apps2.contractorconnection.com", "https://apps2.contractorconnection.com").AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    app.UseOptions();
    //For JWT Auth
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Controller endpoint

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/LandingPage/Authenticate/{webLogin}/{appName}")]
[HttpOptions]
public JsonResult AuthenticateUser(string webLogin, string appName) {
    string connectionString = _config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
    Auth auth = new Auth(connectionString);
    User obj = new User();
    try {
        bool hasAccess = auth.Load(webLogin, appName);
        obj.Name = auth.Name;
        obj.ResourceTypeName = auth.ResourceTypeName;
        obj.ClassificationName = auth.ClassificationName;
        obj.Login = auth.Login;
        obj.ResourceID = auth.ResourceID;
        obj.DetailID = auth.DetailID;
        obj.ApplicationID = auth.ApplicationID;
        obj.ResourceTypeID = auth.ResourceTypeID;
        obj.ClassificationID = auth.ClassificationID;
        obj.SecurityFeatures = auth.FeatureAccess;
        obj.CurrentLanguageDescription = auth.CurrentLanguageDescription;
        obj.CurrentLanguageID = auth.CurrentLanguageID;
        var tokenString = BuildToken(obj);
        obj.Token = tokenString;

        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://test-apps2.contractorconnection.com");

        return Json(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        string ac = ex.Message;
        return Json(obj);
    }
}
```

Web.config

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
        <add origin="*" allowed="true" />
    </cors>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\ERCore_Service.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: IIS has a CORS module.

Comment: @LexLi I installed the module and had no success

Comment: The module won't work automatically, unless you give valid configuration, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: @LexLi that still did not work, I added my Web.config to the post for verification.

Comment: This issue might could be related to another layer security on our servers.  I have another dev I work with checking on something/says he knows whats wrong. Ill have an answer either today or tomorrow if the issue is not with the code or IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a third party software called [Netscaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetScaler). Which was blocking the OPTIONS preflight request being sent by angular.

NetScaler does CORs configuration for the server, so you do not need to configure CORs in the .NET Core api.

If CORs is enabled in the .NET Core API you will get a CORs error for multiple url named in the Allow-Access-Control-Headers.

I removed the CORs configuration from my API and my partner DEV configured CORs and though Netscaler.

This completely solved the issue.